# Bootstrap datepicker: RTL is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using a Bootstrap datepicker for a web project. Here is the datepicker:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

According to the documentation (at the page bottom of the above link), I should use rtl:true for RTL languages. I tried that, but it was not working. Basically, it has no effect. Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker.css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
        <script src=bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" id="dp2">

        <script>
            $('#dp2').datepicker({
                rtl: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: adding locale-specific javascript or specifying a language as follows does not make RTL work based on my tests. It only changes the language strings, but not make content such as date numbers right-to-left.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'XX' // as defined in bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js
});
```

Does anyone know what went wrong and the fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working after digging through the code. In order for RTL to work, you need to load a script such as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

The loaded javascript must have something like this

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['XX'] = {
.....
        rtl: true
    };
```

In addition, your javascript must have the following:

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'XX' 
})

It appears that rtl:true is not needed in the above as the documentation says.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 7):

if you didn't want to change the language and need to fix it, You can fix it by adding some code to your CSS file

```
.datepicker-dropdown {max-width: 300px;}
.datepicker {float: right}
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {right:auto}
```

Note: this code will overwrite the default one so, put it below the file to work

Answer (score 2):

Also add this CSS to prevent from extra large size on RTL screen.

```
.datepicker-dropdown {max-width: 300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this custom style and make sure it is loaded after the bootstrap

```
.datepicker {
   float: right
}
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
   right:auto
}
```

Note: if you found that the dropdown is too far the input field, try to make the input field's width small.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding those lines in the Site.css file:

```css
  /*To display datepicker in RTL*/
.datepicker-dropdown {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.datepicker {
    float: right
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
        right: auto
    }
```

and also edit rtl = true in the bootstrap-datepicker.js file.